# Sort two arrays based on the length of one

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays and the data is combined, like:
[maximilian,moritz,hans] and
[5,1,2000]

Now I have to sort the first array based on the length of the names and keep the numbers at the right spot. The result should be:
[hans,moritz,maximilian]
[2000,1,5]

Normally you can combine both arrays, sort them and then separate them. Simple. But in my case the numbers have different lengths, so the right ordering isn't guaranteed.
If i combine and sort then, the result gonna be:
[moritz,hans,maximilian]
[1,2000,5]
and this is wrong.
Anyone has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide your coded attempt? - I have a subtle solution to problems such as this.

Comment: You should change your data structure. Keeping two arrays associated like that will always lead to trouble

Comment: My data structure is a table, so i cant rlly change it

Comment: @Introser why can't it be changed? You do realise, you can still maintain the same functionality with a slightly different structure, and if anything, an array of objects **in my opinion** is closer to being a table like structure than multiple arrays, or at least use multi dimensional arrays?

Comment: @introser you can. Change the array of columns into an array of rows.

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V I mean, i cant change the given 2 arrays. I can make a multi dimensional array and stuff like that, but the start situation is 2 arrays.

Comment: result `['hans','moritz','maximilian'] [2000,1,5]` how do you decide this type of sorting ?

Comment: @Introser you can still create an array of objects from the two arrays, just like you can make a multi dimensional array, the starting point isn't that relevant is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take the indices, sort them and map the values for both arrays.

```js
var array1 = ['maximilian', 'moritz', 'hans'],
    array2 = [5, 1, 2000],
    indices = array1.map((_, i) => i);
    
indices.sort((a, b) => array1[a].length - array1[b].length);

array1 = indices.map(i => array1[i]);
array2 = indices.map(i => array2[i]);

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow. 3 temporary arrays to sort once :)

Comment: i see only one temp array.

Comment: nice. How about `indices = [...array1.keys()]` ?

Comment: @georg, nice, didn't know that.

Comment: Only **bad** thing I have to say about this answer is **IE (or people that live in the stone age)**. That is all. Other than that, good job! Very simple, very neat, good answer all round.

Answer (score 0):

Create a single array of objects in the form of

```
var array = [{name: hans, number: 2000}, {name: moritz, number: 1}, {name: maximilian, number: 5}];
```

Then you can sort by the key `name` without having to worry about the numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Map` to sort both arrays:

```js
let a1 = ['maximilian', 'moritz', 'hans'],
    a2 = [5, 1, 2000];

(map => {
    a1.sort(({length:s1}, {length:s2}) => s1 - s2);
    a2 = a1.map(s => map.get(s));
})(new Map(a1.map((v, i) => [v, a2[i]])));

console.log(a1);
console.log(a2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Docs:**

- [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values)
- [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Object Destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)
- [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score -1):

I would make an array of objects, combining both arrays into one, then sort them by key, and then splitting them again.

```
const arr1 = [ 'maximilian', 'moritz', 'hans' ]
const arr2 = [5, 1, 2000]

const tmp = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    tmp.push({ key: arr1[i], val: arr2[i] });
}

tmp.sort((a, b) => a.val < b.val);

console.log(tmp);

const keys = tmp.reduce((sub, elem) => { sub.push(elem.key); return sub }, []);
const vals = tmp.reduce((sub, elem) => { sub.push(elem.val); return sub }, []);

console.log(keys);
console.log(vals);
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I was thinking, only I didn't state this as an answer as I have no idea about how his code currently works or if for some bizarre reason they need to be arrays.

Comment: I'm coding it, wait a few minutes and I will edit my post with the code

Comment: Good lad! - It's probably the easiest option possible.

Comment: `const keys = tmp.map(el => el.key)` ?